# Why does not hook_menu_link_alter() work?

Tags: 7, routes

i want to expand my theme's primary links, so I put the following code in my custom module.

```
function mymodulename_menu_link_alter(&$item, $menu) {
  if ($item['menu_name'] == 'primary-links') {
    $item['expanded'] = 1;
  }
}
```

In page.tpl.php I used `print theme('links', $primary_links)`, but the primary links didn't expand. Why?

Answer (score 19):

Not really a complete answer, but [hook_menu_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/6) is not called when the menu is rendered; it is called when the menu item is saved. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Try after flushing the menu cache. For that, the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module will help you.

Comment: This is the real answer which deserves to marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Start with simple things first. Use the Menu Example in the [Examples Project](http://drupal.org/project/examples). The [menu_example_menu_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/menu_example--menu_example.module/function/menu_example_menu_link_alter/6) changes a link... You can use it there and experiment easily.